# Best methods for drawing an interactive 2D plot in MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics

I'm developing a MacOS application in Swift where users record keyframe values against a 2D timeline. My points are stored as a dictionary where the keys are times and the values are the corresponding value at that time.

I have no problem at all plotting my points as a static 2D line graph, and drawing circles on the line to indicate the actual recorded data points. Even with very large numbers of data points it's very snappy to draw lines, even including recalculating and drawing the line in "real-time" during recording.

Where I get stuck is then taking my 2D plot and turning it into an "interactive" plot where the user can select one or more points and then drag them around, altering the stored points in the corresponding data.

What I have been trying so far is drawing my line in my NSView, then instead of drawing the circles for each point as a NSBezierPath, I create an instance of a custom NSView for each point that draws the circle and contains all the mouseDown/mouseDragged/etc. functions and add it as a subview of the main line view. While this "technically" works, it grinds the machine to a halt as it calculates and drops all these views, and obviously more points equals more drag.

Am I missing some way of accomplishing this in a more efficient way? I've been searching and while there are a million and one frameworks and methods for drawing 2D plots of large data sets, I haven't found a single example of one that has "interactive" user-manipulation of the data.

Comment: How many data points will you be working with?  Is a NSPoint array out of the question?

Comment: Hundreds, possibly thousands. I imagine I could convert my point dictionary into an NSPoint array fairly easily. Is there some display advantage to using NSPoint?

Comment: I've just always used NSPoint arrays for projects like this and have no experience with using dictionaries.  The approach that I would take goes something like this: 1) get data and store it in an array 2) create a path from the data using squares or circles for the data pts and connect with lines. 3) Check for ptInRect with mouseDown event 4) Allow repositioning of the data pt with the mouse, update array accordingly and redraw the path.

Comment: Hmm...so on a mouseDown you just do a ptInRect check iterating across all the points in your array? I may experiment with that, since it may solve my issue. I also need to be able to select-drag multiple points at once, so I will have to play around with how I can track which points are selected or not, but I think it's a promising idea. Thanks!

Comment: >so on a mouseDown you just do a ptInRect check iterating across all the points in your array? Correct. I have no experience with multiple point selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demo uses a data array of NSPoints to create an interactive graph which allows the data points to be individually moved with the mouse.  It does not address multiple point selection and will be need to be scaled up to suit your needs (I haven’t tested it with more than 20 points; hopefully it won’t bog down).  The demo may be run from the Command Line in Terminal or in Xcode by adding a ‘main.swift’ file and replacing the existing AppDelegate with the corresponding class below.

```
// May be run in Terminal using:
// swiftc ptinrect.swift -framework Cocoa -o ptinrect && ./ptinrect
// or in Xcode with instructions above.

import Cocoa

let path = NSBezierPath()
var R = [NSRect]()
var selected = [Bool]()
var data = [NSPoint]()

class CustomView: NSView {

override func draw(_ rect: NSRect ) {
 let bkgrnd = NSBezierPath(rect: rect)
 NSColor.lightGray.set()
 bkgrnd.fill()
// circles
 NSColor.black.set()
 for x in stride(from:0, to:R.count, by:1) {
 let circle = NSBezierPath(ovalIn:R[x])
  circle.fill()
 }
// lines
 NSColor.white.set()
 path.lineWidth = 2.0
 path.move(to:data[0])
 for x in stride(from:0, to:data.count, by:1) {
  path.line(to:data[x])
 }
 path.stroke()
}

override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
  let wndPt: NSPoint = event.locationInWindow
  let pt:NSPoint = self.convert(wndPt, from: nil)
  print(pt)
  print(R.count)
  for x in stride(from:0, to:R.count, by:1) {
   if NSPointInRect(pt,R[x]){
   selected[x] = true
   print("mouse down in rect: \(x)")
   print([selected])
   } else {selected[x] = false}
  }
}

override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
 let wndPt: NSPoint = event.locationInWindow
 let pt:NSPoint = self.convert(wndPt, from: nil)
  print(pt)
  for x in stride(from:0, to:R.count, by:1) {
   if NSPointInRect(pt,R[x]){
   print("mouse up in rect: \(x)")
   }
  }
 path.removeAllPoints()
 self.needsDisplay = true
}

override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
 let wndPt: NSPoint = event.locationInWindow
 let pt:NSPoint = self.convert(wndPt, from: nil)
  for x in stride(from:0, to:R.count, by:1) {
   if (selected[x] == true){
   print("mouse dragged in rect: \(x)")
   data[x] = pt
   R[x].origin.x = pt.x - 5
   R[x].origin.y = pt.y - 5
   }
  }
 path.removeAllPoints()
 self.needsDisplay = true
}

}

class ApplicationDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
 var window: NSWindow!

func buildPath() {
var count: CGFloat = 0
 for x in stride(from:0, to:20, by:1) {
  let offset = CGFloat(count * 20.0)
  data.append(NSPoint.init())
  data[x] = NSMakePoint( 20 + offset, 20 + offset)
  R.append(NSRect.init())
  // x,y coordinates -5 to center rect on data pt
  R[x] = NSMakeRect(data[x].x - 5,data[x].y - 5,10,10)
  selected.append(Bool.init())
  selected[x] = false
  count += 1
 }
 print([data])
 path.move(to:data[0])
  for x in stride(from:0, to:data.count, by:1) {
  path.line(to:data[x])
 }
}

func buildMenu() {
let mainMenu = NSMenu()
NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu
// **** App menu **** //
let appMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
mainMenu.addItem(appMenuItem)
let appMenu = NSMenu()
appMenuItem.submenu = appMenu
appMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q")
}

func buildWnd() {
let _wndW : CGFloat = 800
let _wndH : CGFloat = 600

window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH ), styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
 window.center()
 window.title = "Swift Test Window"
 window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)

// **** Custom view **** //
 let view = CustomView( frame:NSMakeRect(20, 60, _wndW - 40, _wndH - 80))
 view.autoresizingMask = [.maxXMargin,.minYMargin, .height, .width]
 window.contentView!.addSubview (view)

// **** Quit btn **** //
 let quitBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 10, 40, 40 ))
 quitBtn.bezelStyle = .circular
 quitBtn.autoresizingMask = [.minXMargin,.maxYMargin]
 quitBtn.title = "Q"
 quitBtn.action = #selector(NSApplication.terminate)
 window.contentView!.addSubview(quitBtn)
}

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
 buildMenu()
 buildWnd()
 buildPath()
}

func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
 return true
}

}
let appDelegate = ApplicationDelegate()

// **** main.swift **** //
let application = NSApplication.shared
application.setActivationPolicy(NSApplication.ActivationPolicy.regular)
application.delegate = appDelegate
application.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
application.run()
```

Comment: I haven't gone exactly this route, but even with my current data structures, the key I seemed to be missing was handling drawing the points and lines on a single plane as you suggested, instead of trying to add a unique subview for each point, then tracking the NSRect of each point for mouseDown hit-test purposes. So I'm happy to mark this as answered. Thanks!